# Find the last value in a row where cell value string has a length of 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to the find the last value in a row where the cell value has a total  length of 1 - can either be an alpha character or a number. Example of Excel row:

A 18-Aug-16 PDR B 21-Oct-16 PDR 0 04-Nov-16 CDR
[image: SO40498388 Q example]

Formula used:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(E21:Q21<>""),E21:Q21)
```

Result is  **CDR** (which is three character lengths).

I need the formula to show the result as **0** which is the last 1 character length cell in the row.

The formula needs to look at all the 1 character length cells and return the last one in the row which can be alpha or number.

Comment: A is cell E21, 18-Aug-16 is cell F21, PDR is cell G21, B is cell H21, 21-Oct-16 is cell I21, PDR is cell J21, 0 is cell K21, 04-Nov-16 is cell L21, CDR is cell M21 .  Each row can have varying columns filled in, eg a row might only have 3 columns filled in, another row may have 9 columns filled in - thank you.

Comment: `=INDEX(E21:Q21,1,MAX(COLUMN(E21:Q21)*(LEN(E21:Q21)=1))-COLUMN(E21)+1)  ` entered as an array formula. Not pretty but works...

Comment: thanks for your reply.   Used the formula but returns #VALUE! , any ideas why formula not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?
[image]

```
=OFFSET(E1,0,COUNTA(E1:M1)-3)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much for your help, works perfectly.  One question can you advise what the -3 at the end of the formula means please.

Comment: Your are welcome ."a row might only have 3 columns filled in, another row may have 9 columns filled in ".  So I think every 3 as a group.